# Is there a limitation for force:hasRecordId not working on user record page?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I am trying to get the recordid from a user record page. My debug logs turns to be null.

```
getDataClass: function (component) {

    var action = component.get("c.getTableData");

    action.setParams({
        "recordId" : component.get("v.recordId")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
      var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var resultData = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('resultData..' + resultData);

    }
});
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

```
        public static List<dataClass> getTableData(Id UserId) {

            System.debug('RECORDID' + UserId);
```

Comment: Can you check the component code, force:hasRecordId is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation)

> This interface has no effect except when used within Lightning
>   Experience, the Salesforce mobile app, and template-based communities.

You need to find another way for getting the userId.

Answer (score 4):

There has no such limitation that you can't get the record id on User Record page through force:hasRecordId. I have tried a simple code and it works perfectly fine:-

**Component:-**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    the record id is:- {!v.recordId}
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:-**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert("user record id "+ component.get("v.recordId"));
    }
})
```

See the image below:-

[image]

The reason you are not getting the recordid in your apex class is you are setting parameter as below:-

```
action.setParams({
        "recordId" : component.get("v.recordId")
});
```

In your apex method you have:-

```
public static List<dataClass> getTableData(Id UserId) {
}
```

> So instead using recordId in action.setParams, you should use UserId
>   to pass the value.

The correct piece of code will be:-

```
action.setParams({
        "UserId" : component.get("v.recordId")
});
```